# Emotional Intelligence and perceiving emotions

Tags: emotion, emotional-intelligence

One of the components of Emotional Intelligence is to be able perceive emotions in oneself:

"Salovey and Mayer's conception of EI strives to define EI within the confines of the standard criteria for a new intelligence. (...) However, after pursuing further research, their definition of EI evolved into "the capacity to reason about emotions, and of emotions, to enhance thinking. **It includes the abilities to accurately perceive emotions**, to access and generate emotions so as to assist thought, to understand emotions and emotional knowledge, and to reflectively regulate emotions so as to promote emotional and intellectual growth."
(Wikipedia)

But to my understanding, theories of emotions know consider that an emotion involve the appraisal, so that you can not have an emotion without being aware of it.